# Why is the map.server virtual path not being saved to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, fileinfo, virtual-path

I have been stuck on saving the virtual path of a file upload to my db. Without the virtual path the file is being saved and the url in the db is the physical path of the file. so when i try to download it I am getting the local resource not allowed. the url starts with file:///C:path....
When i use break points I see that the physical path is being changed to the virtual path, however it exceptions out.

apiController

```
//POST
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {

        try
        {
            //saving the posted file to the harddisk
            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            //Get Logged in User Name
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            //getting the user details and storing in the object
            Document model = new Document();
            model.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["TypeId"]);
            model.TypeName = provider.FormData["TypeName"];
            model.PipeName = provider.FormData["PipeName"];
            model.DocumentUrl = provider.FormData["DocumentUrl"];
            model.DocumentUrl = model.DocumentUrl == "" ? null : model.DocumentUrl;

            //if there is a file then save that file to the desired location
            if (provider.FileData.Count > 0)
            {
                MultipartFileData fileData = provider.FileData[0];
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileData.LocalFileName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(fi.DirectoryName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fi.DirectoryName);
                }
                else
                {
                    //getting the file saving path
                    string clientFileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace(@"""", "");
                    if (clientFileName != "")
                    {
                        string clientExtension = clientFileName.Substring(clientFileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                        string space = ("-");
                        var dt = model.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                        var CompanyName = model.CompanyName.Replace('_', ' ');

                        string vPath = root.Replace(@"C:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy", "~").Replace("\\", "/");
                        string serverFileName = vPath + CompanyName + space + model.TypeName + space + model.CounterPartyName + space + dt + clientExtension;
                        model.DocumentUrl = serverFileName;



                        FileInfo fiOld = new FileInfo(vPath);
                        if (fiOld.Exists)
                            fiOld.Delete();
                        //if (File.Exists())
                        fi.MoveTo(serverFileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fi.Exists)
                            fi.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
            //calling DB to save the user details
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                //save to db
                context.Documents.Add(model);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception fex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, fex);
        }
        //sending the confirmation or error back to the user
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The breakpoint at :

```
model.DocumentUrl = serverFileName;
```

shows

> "~/Files/Black Elk-Invoices-None-May 2006.pdf"

The Exception happens here

```
 FileInfo fiOld = new FileInfo(vPath);
  if (fiOld.Exists)
  fiOld.Delete();
//if (File.Exists())
  fi.MoveTo(serverFileName);
```

The FiloInfo(vPath) shows

> ~/Files/

The Exception happens at :

```
fi.MoveTo(serverFileName);
```

Exception message:

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
>      at System.IO.FileInfo.MoveTo(String destFileName)
>      at TransparentEnergy.ControllersAPI.apiInvoiceController.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy\ControllersAPI\SubmitApi\apiInvoiceController.cs:line 87

Updated

```
 //POST
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {

        try
        {
            //saving the posted file to the harddisk
            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            //Get Logged in User Name
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            //getting the user details and storing in the object
            Document model = new Document();
            model.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["TypeId"]);
            model.TypeName = provider.FormData["TypeName"];
            model.LocationId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["LocationId"]);
            model.LocationName = provider.FormData["LocationName"];
            model.PipeId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["PipeId"]);
            model.PipeName = provider.FormData["PipeName"];
            model.CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["CompanyId"]);
            model.CompanyName = provider.FormData["CompanyName"];
            model.PlantId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["PlantId"]);
            model.PlantName = provider.FormData["PlantName"];
            model.CounterPartyId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["CounterPartyId"]);
            model.CounterPartyName = provider.FormData["CounterPartyName"];
            string docDate = provider.FormData["DocumentDate"];
            model.DocumentDate = DateTime.Parse(docDate.Trim('"'));
            model.UploadedBy = user.Name;
            model.UploadDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.DocumentUrl = provider.FormData["DocumentUrl"];

            //if there is a file then save that file to the desired location
            if (provider.FileData.Count > 0)
            {
                MultipartFileData fileData = provider.FileData[0];
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileData.LocalFileName);

                //getting the file saving path
                string clientFileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace(@"""", "");
                if (clientFileName != "")
                {
                    string clientExtension = clientFileName.Substring(clientFileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                    string dash = ("-");
                    var dt = model.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                    var CompanyName = model.CompanyName.Replace('_', ' ');

                    string vPath = root.Replace(@"C:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy", "~").Replace("\\", "/");
                    string path = String.Format(CompanyName + dash + model.TypeName + dash + model.CounterPartyName + dash + dt + clientExtension);

                    string combination = Path.Combine(vPath, path);
                    model.DocumentUrl = combination;
                    FileInfo fiOld = new FileInfo(path);
                    if (fiOld.Exists)
                        fiOld.Delete();
                    //if (File.Exists())
                    fi.MoveTo(vPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (fi.Exists)
                        fi.Delete();
                }

            }
            //calling DB to save the user details
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                //save to db
                context.Documents.Add(model);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception fex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, fex);
        }
        //sending the confirmation or error back to the user
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

This Works!

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {

        try
        {
            //saving the posted file to the harddisk
            //string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
            string root = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["~/Files/"]);
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            //Get Logged in User Name
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            //getting the user details and storing in the object
            Document model = new Document();
            model.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["TypeId"]);
            model.TypeName = provider.FormData["TypeName"];
            model.LocationId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["LocationId"]);
            model.LocationName = provider.FormData["LocationName"];
            model.PipeId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["PipeId"]);
            model.PipeName = provider.FormData["PipeName"];
            model.CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["CompanyId"]);
            model.CompanyName = provider.FormData["CompanyName"];
            model.PlantId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["PlantId"]);
            model.PlantName = provider.FormData["PlantName"];
            model.CounterPartyId = Convert.ToInt32(provider.FormData["CounterPartyId"]);
            model.CounterPartyName = provider.FormData["CounterPartyName"];
            string docDate = provider.FormData["DocumentDate"];
            model.DocumentDate = DateTime.Parse(docDate.Trim('"'));
            model.UploadedBy = user.Name;
            model.UploadDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.DocumentUrl = provider.FormData["DocumentUrl"];

            //if there is a file then save that file to the desired location
            if (provider.FileData.Count > 0)
            {
                MultipartFileData fileData = provider.FileData[0];
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileData.LocalFileName);

                //getting the file saving path
                string clientFileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace(@"""", "");
                if (clientFileName != "")
                {
                    string clientExtension = clientFileName.Substring(clientFileName.LastIndexOf('.'));

                    var dt = model.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                    var CompanyName = model.CompanyName.Replace('_', ' ');

                    string vPath = root.Replace(@"C:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy", "~").Replace("\\", "/");
                    string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}{4}", CompanyName, model.TypeName, model.CounterPartyName, dt, clientExtension);
                    string combination = Path.Combine(vPath, fileName);
                    model.DocumentUrl = combination;

                    string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Files");
                    string relativePath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, fileName);
                    FileInfo fiOld = new FileInfo(relativePath);
                    if (fiOld.Exists)
                        fiOld.Delete();
                    //if (File.Exists())
                    fi.MoveTo(relativePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (fi.Exists)
                        fi.Delete();
                }

            }
            //calling DB to save the user details
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                //save to db
                context.Documents.Add(model);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception fex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, fex);
        }
        //sending the confirmation or error back to the user
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Comment: No need to do `if (!Directory.Exists(fi.DirectoryName))` because `Directory.CreateDirectory` ["creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, these two lines are really confusing: `model.DocumentUrl = provider.FormData["DocumentUrl"];` followed by `model.DocumentUrl = model.DocumentUrl == "" ? null : model.DocumentUrl;`.

Comment: ok, got rid of both. the model.DucmentUrl == "" ? null should have not been there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue happens because the (badly named) `serverFileName` in `fi.MoveTo(serverFileName);` actually points to a virtual path instead of to a physical path.

Note that I'd really advise to rethink your code. Some examples:

- `string space = ("-");`: "-" isn't a space.
- `model.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');` looks like a bad way to format a date.
- `string serverFileName = vPath + CompanyName + space + model.TypeName + space + model.CounterPartyName + space + dt + clientExtension;` First, use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to join a folder and a filename. Second, wouldn't it be better to use `string.Format` to create the name of the file instead of a long concatenation? Third, `serverFileName` is IMHO a bad name, I'd call this a path.
- I really don't get what is happening with `model.DocumentUrl`: first it gets the value of `provider.FormData["DocumentUrl"]`, then you check if `model.DocumentUrl` is an empty string (note that it is preferred to use `string.Empty`) and set it to NULL if that's the case, and then you assign it `serverFileName`.

Comment: ok, I followed your advice. Is the date poorly formatted or is it because of the chosen format? I changed variables and used Path.Combine and string.Format. I removed the second model.DocumentUrl. Same result. I updated the code. I believe I have the FileInfo fiOld = new FileInfo(path); correct

Comment: In your updated code, `FileInfo fiOld = new FileInfo(path);` now points to a file name, not a path. But even if you'd use `combination`, that still would be a **virtual** path (e.g. "~/Files/") and AFAIK FileInfo requires a **physical** path (e.g. "c:\files\"). Ditto for `fi.MoveTo(vPath);`. Also, your string.Format is incorrect, it should be `string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}{4}", CompanyName, model.TypeName, model.CounterPartyName, dt, clientExtension);`.

Comment: so I would get the physical path like this string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Files");  and then use that in the FiloInfo(physicalPath)